# In vb.net, defining a dictionary type in a class

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

New to using a Dictionary list.

I have an api that is returning a "task object" defined as:

id As Integer

options As Dictionary(string, string)

So I am defining a class called Task to store the returned "task object".

```
Public Class Task
   Private _id As Integer

   Public Property Id() As Integer
      Get
           Return _id
      End Get

       Set(value As Integer
           _id = value
       End Set
   End Property

  Private _optionlist As New List(Of Option)

  Public Property OptionList() As List(Of Option)
      Get
          Return _optionlist
      End Get

      Set(ByVal value As List(Of Option))
          _optionlist = value
      End Set
  End Property
End Class

Public Class Option
   Private _key As String

   Public Property Key() As String
      Get
          Return _key
      End Get

      Set(value As String)
          _key = value
      End Set
  End Property

  Private _value As String

  Public Property Value() As String
      Get
          Return _value
      End Get

      Set(value As String)
          _value = value
      End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

I will assign the "task object" returned from the api to this Task class.
I defined options as a **list**. Is that correct?

I will also have to read the option in my class and later repopulate it to send back to the api via function call.

Could use some help...thanks.

Comment: A Dictionary and a List are different collections, but I have no idea what a Dictionary means in the context of that API.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2010 or later, you could drastically reduce the amount of code by using [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: I would also avoid using keywords and NET Type names as classes, props etc (Task and Option).  It sort of looks like you are angling to create your own sort of KVP with that option class.  Not needed with a real NET Dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the property to the class directly:

```
Public Class Task
  Private _id As Integer
  Private options As Dictionary(of string, string)
```

You can also create Get and Set methods for the "options" parameter.

Comment: Makes sense...no need for that additional "option" class. I would just need to loop thru the "options" dictionary once i load the "Task" class...Thanks.